# How to fix non-responsive featured boxes in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a responsive wordpress theme but my featured boxes are not responsive in tablet or mobile mode. They appear stretched out and much bigger than their original size. I tried adding media queries to the css stylesheet and using various plugins but I don't know what else to do. All the other images on my site are responsive on all devices.

This is the media query I tried using:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1139px) {
div.featured-box {
    margin-top: 135px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
div.featured-box {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
}
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: it is in admin panel?

Comment: unfortunately it's not, I checked. I tried making my homepage static, I thought that would help with the sizing but nothing changed.

Comment: post your html code also